# Radio communications system - Uniform density question

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Full question: In a radio communications system, the phase difference $X $ between the transmitter and receiver is modeled as having a uniform density in $[—\pi, +\pi]$. Find $P(X \le 0)$ and $P(X \le \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. The probability density function of $X$ is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2\pi} & \mathrm{for}\ -\pi \le x \le \pi, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<-\pi\ \mathrm{or}\ x>\pi
  \end{cases}
$$ then you have
$$
P(X\leq0)=\int_{-\infty}^0f(x)\:dx
$$
$$
P\left(X\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\pi/2}f(x)\:dx.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you but it's confusing me because i don't know what's f(x).

Comment: You are welcome. $f(x)$ is defined in the first part of my answer. For example $P(X\leq0)=\int_{-\infty}^0f(x)\:dx$ is reduced to $P(X\leq0)=\int_{-\pi}^0\frac1{2\pi}\:dx$ which is easy to evaluate. Is it Ok?

Comment: how did you get 1/2pi?

Comment: You may apply this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Characterization with $a=-\pi$, $b=\pi$ giving $b-a=2\pi$.

Comment: @Ayechan_San because $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \operatorname d x=1$ and $f(x)$ is constant over the support (it is uniform).